# Javascript: Simulate a click in <input type="file">

Tags: javascript

Good day,

I'm trying to simulate a click on a browse file element but I couldn't make it work.

I found this:
http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/03/05/simulate-a-button-click-via-javascript/

and tried and it works in 'button' and 'submit' types:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="document.getElementById('theSubmitButton').click();">Check the box to simulate a button click
<input type="submit" name="theSubmitButton" id="theSubmitButton" value="Button" onClick="alert('The button was clicked.');">
```

but when I tried to change it to 'file' type:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="document.getElementById('theSubmitButton').click();">Check the box to simulate a button click
<input type="file" name="theSubmitButton" id="theSubmitButton" value="Button" onClick="alert('The button was clicked.');">
```

It wouldn't work in Firefox and IE8. But the file browser window appears in Google Chrome.

Is there a problem with this approach? How could I make it work in FF and IE8?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a security restriction to prevent malicious javascript from uploading files from a users computer without him wanting that or tricking him in doing so by opening a file selection dialog. You can't do it in javascript, and it's not a bug, it's a feature.

Comment: Just an addition to this answer: if you need to open file dialog at random time - you can use flash-based uploaders.

Comment: "security", "feature"

Answer (score 0):

It also depends, why you need this? If this is for testing purposes you can use some existing frameworks, like FuncUnit:

http://www.beletsky.net/2010/12/functional-testing-by-javascript-with.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just want to reduce the number of clicks the user must do, but I guess I can't. Thanks for your link, I might use it someday. :)