# problem in file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I have the following markup:

```
  <select multiple="multiple" id="targetFilesList"  style="width:200px;height:110px;">
   </select>
   <input type="button" value="Get" id="btnGet" />
```

and following javascript:

```
    $(function()
    {
        $('#btnGet').click(function()
        {
            var fileupload = $("<input type='file' name='filetoupload' style='visibility:hidden;'/>");
            $('body').append(fileupload);

            fileupload[0].onchange = function()
            {
                $('#targetFilesList').append('<option >' + fileupload.val() + '</option>');
                return false;
            }
            fileupload.click();
        });
    });
```

Scenario is that i have to upload multiple files and once user has chosen the file to be uploaded i have to show the file name to user.Then,on submitting the form i will upload all the files.For this,on clicking the get button i am adding a fileupload control dynamically
and initialise onchange event of the fileupload control just added. The problem in chrome 12 on clicking get button fileupload control does not get opened but in firefox4 and ie8 it is working.
Any idea why?

Comment: Not able to reproduce.. working on Chrome 12 for me.  JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/gfosco/JKK4w/

Comment: sorry Fosco.I forgot to mention that if i place alert then is is working and if i remove it then it is not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Simulate a click in <input type="file">](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451652/javascript-simulate-a-click-in-input-type-file)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get it working on Chrome 12, you can just add it into a window timeout of 0, like this:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
   fileupload.click();   
},0);
```

Why exactly it behaves like this, I am not sure. The first time I encountered the problem I tried it with a longer interval, reducing it all the time to see how low you could get it, until I noticed it doesn't even need a delay. The obvious answer would be that it isn't actually ready in DOM by the time you trigger the click (element is there, but is the appropriate events for it?).

example: http://jsfiddle.net/HgEga/

Comment: The reason for this behaviour is due to the way chrome optimizes page re-rendering according to the js runtime. Since the whole thing is single threaded, and a setTimeout forces a callstack-break, you effectvly tell chrome "now it is time to re-render the page" when you do the settimeout. You can fuind this problem in all major browsers in various situations when you append new elements to the DOM while running js code around the append.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this kind of code yourself can be a pain. Maybe taking a look to an [existing multiple file upload jQuery plugin](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload) will help.